# Riemann integral in an open interval

Tags: real-analysis

I do not understand where my "proof" for the following question went wrong. The grader marked it wrong and I need a strong case before I request partial credit.

*Prompt*

Suppose that for all $a \in (A,B)$, $f$ is integrable in $[a,B]$. Show that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[A,B]$.

---

I got the feeling that the prompt is incorrect, say $f(x) = (1-A)^{-1}$, but since this was part of a larger question where $f$ is bounded, I played along.

---

*Proof.* By hypothesis, we have that the integral
$$
\int^B_a f(x) dx = \int^B_{A^+} f(x) dx
$$
exists. Because this is a Riemann integral, then
$$
\int^α_α g = \int^α_{α^-} g = \int^{α^+}_{α^-} g = \int^{a^+}_{α} g = 0.
$$
Thus,
$$
\int^B_A f(x) dx = \int^{A^+}_{A} f(x) dx + \int_{A^+}^{B} f(x) dx = 0 + \int_{A^+}^{B} f(x) dx
$$
exists.

Comment: For the uninitiated, you'll need to define $A^+$ etc

Comment: If $f$ is bounded, you can subdivise in two part $[A,A+\delta]$ and $[A+\delta,B]$ and upper bound the first integral so the sum is belwo the $\varepsilon$ required for (Riemann) integrability. I think the problem is the way you have written the argument. It is not blatantly false, as far as I understand the notations, but confusing and not very rigorous.

Comment: The first problem is your equation $$\int_a f(x)\; dx = \int_{A^+}^B f(x)\; dx$$ is completely wrong.  You're stating that a limit (which may or may not exist) is equal to the thing it's supposed to be the limit of.